# Drobo 5N giving me network errors

Tags: hard-drive, drobo

I have a Drobo 5N that's giving me network errors when I try to save files to it. The start of the errors correlates with me replacing one drive and adding one drive. The problem is that all drives look green and I forgot which ones I added. I remember that as soon I added the drives, I could hear constant disk noise.

Is there a way to see a log to see if one drive is having issues?

Comment: What does the Drobo Dashboard indicate?  Can you specify what the errors are?

Comment: Depending on the size of the disk, and the number of disks, it can take upwards of several hours for the Drobo to prepare the new drive.  Rebooting the Drobo during this phase is not recommended.  **I speak from experience as a Drobo 5N2 owner.**

Comment: @Ramhound: it's been more than 30 days and I did watch the status report of the state of the disks. When I changed disks before, there was no correlation between a disk change and network errors.